# Highlight (Colored) Watched Tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, tag-watching

I have a few watched tags I would like to pay attention to. But the problem is when I'm going through StackExchange questions, sometimes I have to double check to see whether I have subscribed to that tag or not. This a problem when you don't remember all tags that you're subscribed. This could be easily avoided if we can easily identity watched tags from other tags.

However, this should not be aggressive or distractive. Users must always be able to focus on the questions.

This is an example...

Normal (without the feature): Watched  Tag: [password-management](/questions/tagged/password-management)

[image: Screenshot-Normal]

Highlight (after feature implemented): Watched Tag: [password-management](/questions/tagged/password-management)

[image: Screenshot-Highlighted]

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not opposed to this idea, I'd just like to draw your attention to the right sidebar, where there is a widget which shows you which tags you watch:

[image]

You won't see it if you scroll far enough down the list, but I'd wager it works as a decent workaround for the time being.

Comment: Thank you for responding. :) Yes, it works but like you said, if you scroll down, then you have to scroll up just to check the tag. In addition, if you have subscribed many tags (30+ or more), then it'll take a couple (unnecessary) seconds to check it. There is also another option. You can just hover the mouse pointer over (mouseover) that tag and it'll show whether you're subscribed or not. However, this won't work when you're going through StackExchange questions. (hot, real-time). Again, this is not a major design flaw or anything like that, but it'll be easier if we can have this.